# Outermost Minimal Surface in a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

An outermost minimal surface is a minimal surface which does not contain another minimal surface within it.  Interestingly, outer minimal surfaces are always spheres, because the only other possibility (that they might be tori) is removed via a stability argument.

If a Riemannian $3$-manifold $(M,g)$ contains an outermost minimal surface, will a small perturbation of that manifold (ie. the metric is $g+h$, where $h$ is some small perturbation) also have that same outermost minimal surface, or will that surface also have a perturbation added to it?

Comment: Can you clarify what does within means? Is your minimal surface $S$ a boundary $S = \partial U$ and an outmost minimal surface has no other minimal surface in $U$?

Comment: Are you following the definition in p.4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9911173.pdf)?

Comment: Yes it should be the same definition as that paper, I might have mixed the definition up slightly as I gave it.

Comment: For example, on page 10 of that article one takes a manifold $M^3,g_0$ with an outer minimizing horizon $\Sigma_0$.  If we perturb the metric $g_0$ by a small amount, will that also make a corresponding change to the outer minimizing horizon?